# Finding first occurence of a value in every group R

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

I have this dataset about each machine in a lab,

```
 MachineID InstalledDate SwitchedOnDate Status
 1           2010-02-18    2010-02-19    SleepMode
 1           2010-02-18    2010-02-20    Active
 1           2010-02-18    2010-02-21    SleepMode
 1           2010-02-18    2010-02-22    Active
 2           2010-02-20    2010-02-21    Active
 2           2010-02-20    2010-02-22    SleepMode
 3           2010-02-10    2010-02-18    SleepMode
 4           2010-03-10    2010-03-15    SleepMode
```

I am trying to find out how many days it took for each machine to go Active for the first time from Installed Date. So that is "SwitchedOnDate - InstalledDate".

Comment: Do you just want the difference in time for each row in days? Or, do you want it for only the first Active Status for each machine?

Comment: I want it for only the first Active Status for each machine.

Comment: Subset to include only `Active` rows, then de-duplicate on MachineID and Status, and what you'll have left is the first time each  machine was activated. As you say, `SwitchedOnDate - InstalledDate`.

Comment: @Gregor Thanks for your suggestions. Yeah that works too.

Comment: Hey, one thing i just realized after plotting them is "Installed Date" is wrong for some machines. So providing incorrect insights. I am thinking of using [SwitchedOnDate for first "Active" - "First SwitchedOnDate" for that machine irrespective of the status] to find out the days, how can we do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following @Gregor's and @Frank's comments, a better approach is to use `distinct` to retain only the (first) unique rows for each `MachineID` instead of grouping by `MachineID`:

```
library(dplyr)
res <- df %>% filter(Status=="Active") %>%
              distinct(MachineID, .keep_all=TRUE) %>%
              mutate(Days.Go.Active=difftime(SwitchedOnDate,InstalledDate,units="days"))
print(res)
##Source: local data frame [2 x 5]
##Groups: MachineID [2]
##
##  MachineID InstalledDate SwitchedOnDate Status Days.Go.Active
##      <int>        <date>         <date>  <chr> <S3: difftime>
##1         1    2010-02-18     2010-02-20 Active         2 days
##2         2    2010-02-20     2010-02-21 Active         1 days
```

---

With `dplyr`, you can `mutate` using `difftime` to compute the difference in units of `"days"`:

```
library(dplyr)
res <- df %>% group_by(MachineID) %>% 
              filter(Status=="Active") %>%
              filter(row_number()==1) %>%
              mutate(Days.Go.Active=difftime(SwitchedOnDate,InstalledDate,units="days"))
print(res)
##Source: local data frame [2 x 5]
##Groups: MachineID [2]
##
##  MachineID InstalledDate SwitchedOnDate Status Days.Go.Active
##      <int>        <date>         <date>  <chr> <S3: difftime>
##1         1    2010-02-18     2010-02-20 Active         2 days
##2         2    2010-02-20     2010-02-21 Active         1 days
```

Here, we `group_by` `MachineID` and then use `filter` to keep only first row from each group that have `Status` of `Active`.

---

**Data:**

```
df <- structure(list(MachineID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L), 
    InstalledDate = structure(c(14658, 14658, 14658, 14658, 14660, 
    14660, 14650, 14678), class = "Date"), SwitchedOnDate = structure(c(14659, 
    14660, 14661, 14662, 14661, 14662, 14658, 14683), class = "Date"), 
    Status = c("SleepMode", "Active", "SleepMode", "Active", 
    "Active", "SleepMode", "SleepMode", "SleepMode")), .Names = c("MachineID", 
"InstalledDate", "SwitchedOnDate", "Status"), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = "data.frame")
##  MachineID InstalledDate SwitchedOnDate    Status
##1         1    2010-02-18     2010-02-19 SleepMode
##2         1    2010-02-18     2010-02-20    Active
##3         1    2010-02-18     2010-02-21 SleepMode
##4         1    2010-02-18     2010-02-22    Active
##5         2    2010-02-20     2010-02-21    Active
##6         2    2010-02-20     2010-02-22 SleepMode
##7         3    2010-02-10     2010-02-18 SleepMode
##8         4    2010-03-10     2010-03-15 SleepMode
```

---

#### To address updated requirements of using first SwitchedOnDate

```
res <- df %>% group_by(MachineID) %>%
              mutate(FirstSwitchedOnDate=first(SwitchedOnDate)) %>%
              filter(Status=="Active") %>%
              filter(row_number()==1) %>%
              mutate(Days.Go.Active=as.numeric(difftime(SwitchedOnDate,FirstSwitchedOnDate,units="days"))) %>%
              select(-FirstSwitchedOnDate)
##Source: local data frame [2 x 5]
##Groups: MachineID [2]
##
##  MachineID InstalledDate SwitchedOnDate Status Days.Go.Active
##      <int>        <date>         <date>  <chr>          <dbl>
##1         1    2010-02-18     2010-02-20 Active              1
##2         2    2010-02-20     2010-02-21 Active              0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That is perfect. :)

Comment: @Frank: will do. Missed Gregor's comment while typing :-)

Comment: @Frank Thanks for your suggestions. Yeah that works too.

Comment: of course the default unit for `-.Date` is `"days"`, so no need for `difftime`, but it's good to have in mind that it exists

Comment: What if I dont want that to be days? As I am trying to use that days for some calculation and making plots ?

Comment: @ds_user: yes, you can use `as.numeric` to convert the values from the `difftime` class to numeric. As Michael Chirico said, there is no need for `difftime` here if you want the results in terms of days. However, using `difftime` allows you to compute the difference in other units of time such as `"hours"`.

Comment: Hey, one thing i just realized after plotting them is "Installed Date" is wrong for some machines. So providing incorrect insights. I am thinking of using [SwitchedOnDate for first "Active" - "First SwitchedOnDate" for that machine irrespective of the status] to find out the days, how can we do that? @aichao

Comment: @ds_user: then I would use my first answer, and right after `group_by(MachineID)` `mutate(FirstSwitchedOnDate=first(SwitchOnDate))` This will create a new column recording the first `SwitchOnDate` for each `MachineID`. Then do the filters to get the first Active row and compute the difference using the `FirstSwitchedOnDate`. You can then de-select this column in the final output (i.e., `select(-FirstSwitchedOnDate)`).

Comment: @ds_user: please see my edits to see if that works for you.

Answer (score 4):

In `data.table`, it's basically the same idea:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df) #convert to data.table

df[, SwitchedOnDate[which.max(Status == "Active")] - min(SwitchedonDate),
   by = MachineID]
```

If you've got a name in mind for your output (e.g., `OffDuration`), a slight syntax change:

```
df[Status == "Active",
   .(OffDuration = 
       SwitchedOnDate[which.max(Status == "Active")] - min(SwitchedonDate)),
   by = MachineID]
```

Comment: Does this work only for first "Active" for each machine?

Comment: @ds_user yes, that's what the `1L` is doing -- selecting the first observation within each `MachineID`

Comment: Awesome. Thanks :)

Comment: Hey, one thing i just realized after plotting them is "Installed Date" is wrong for some machines. So providing incorrect insights. I am thinking of using [SwitchedOnDate for first "Active" - "First SwitchedOnDate" for that machine irrespective of the status] to find out the days, how can we do that?